# why do i get this error MeteorWebApp: Asset /socket.io/ not found in bundle?

Tags: android, cordova, vue.js, meteor

I'm having an issue, I'm running `meteor 1.8.1` with `vue`. My app runs okay on web no errors , but when i compile the app for android i get this error in the console MeteorWebApp: Asset /socket.io/ not found in bundle. the app crashes and I'm not sure where to begin.

My packages

```
accounts-base@1.4.3
accounts-password@1.5.1
akryum:npm-check@0.1.1
akryum:vue@1.2.3
akryum:vue-component@0.14.3
akryum:vue-component-dev-client@0.4.5
akryum:vue-component-dev-server@0.1.3
akryum:vue-router2@0.2.2
aldeed:collection2@3.0.2
allow-deny@1.1.0
amplify@1.0.0
autoupdate@1.6.0
babel-compiler@7.3.4
babel-runtime@1.3.0
base64@1.0.11
binary-heap@1.0.11
blaze-tools@1.0.10
boilerplate-generator@1.6.0
caching-compiler@1.2.1
caching-html-compiler@1.1.3
callback-hook@1.1.0
check@1.3.1
cultofcoders:persistent-session@0.4.5
dburles:collection-helpers@1.1.0
ddp@1.4.0
ddp-client@2.3.3
ddp-common@1.4.0
ddp-rate-limiter@1.0.7
ddp-server@2.3.0
deps@1.0.12
diff-sequence@1.1.1
dynamic-import@0.5.1
easysearch:core@2.2.2
ecmascript@0.12.4
ecmascript-runtime@0.7.0
ecmascript-runtime-client@0.8.0
ecmascript-runtime-server@0.7.1
ejson@1.1.0
email@1.2.3
erasaur:meteor-lodash@4.0.0
es5-shim@4.8.0
fetch@0.1.1
fourseven:scss@4.10.0
geojson-utils@1.0.10
hot-code-push@1.0.4
html-tools@1.0.11
htmljs@1.0.11
id-map@1.1.0
inter-process-messaging@0.1.0
jquery@1.11.11
jss:meteor-form-data@0.0.1
launch-screen@1.1.1
livedata@1.0.18
localstorage@1.2.0
logging@1.1.20
matb33:collection-hooks@0.8.4
meteor@1.9.3
meteor-base@1.4.0
minifier-css@1.4.2
minifier-js@2.4.1
minimongo@1.4.5
mobile-experience@1.0.5
mobile-status-bar@1.0.14
modern-browsers@0.1.4
modules@0.13.0
modules-runtime@0.10.3
momentjs:moment@2.24.0
mongo@1.6.2
mongo-decimal@0.1.1
mongo-dev-server@1.1.0
mongo-id@1.0.7
npm-bcrypt@0.9.3
npm-mongo@3.1.2
ordered-dict@1.1.0
promise@0.11.2
raix:eventemitter@0.1.3
random@1.1.0
rate-limit@1.0.9
reactive-dict@1.3.0
reactive-var@1.0.11
reload@1.3.0
retry@1.1.0
routepolicy@1.1.0
service-configuration@1.0.11
session@1.2.0
sha@1.0.9
shell-server@0.4.0
socket-stream-client@0.2.2
spacebars-compiler@1.1.3
srp@1.0.12
standard-minifier-css@1.5.3
standard-minifier-js@2.4.1
static-html@1.2.2
templating-tools@1.1.2
tmeasday:check-npm-versions@0.3.2
tracker@1.2.0
underscore@1.0.10
underscorestring:underscore.string@3.3.4
webapp@1.7.3
webapp-hashing@1.0.9
```

Plugins installed

```
cordova-plugin-geolocation@2.4.3
cordova-plugin-meteor-webapp@1.7.3
cordova-plugin-splashscreen@2.4.3
cordova-plugin-statusbar@2.2.1
```

METEOR@1.8.1

Comment: How did you install socket.io in your project? via some `meteor add` or via `npm install`?

Comment: i didn't install socket.io into the project, that's why i'm a bit confused and am not using socket directly in the project. Does meteor's publish and subscribe functionality use socket.io? and if so why does it work in browser and not in android.

Comment: okay i noticed something if i build for production the app works fine . so im certain that its an HMR issue, probably caused by the Vue akryum package im using with meteor vue integration. So how do i set the HMR_URL ?

Comment: I don't know. What's HMR?

Comment: ooh its the Hot Module Replacement. its used to push changes to the app in development mode without reloading the app or needing to refresh the client.

Comment: so its needs a separate port number to monitor and push changes to the client. so it seems the ip addresses didn't resolve and its giving an error. so im stuck coz im not sure how to configure it properly, the docs are not clear on how to go about it

Comment: Have you tried with vanilla meteor (without Vue)? I would start there, and only once that is working (and it should work out of the box), then add Vue and whatever other packages you need.

Comment: it seems il have to start with plain meteor and then slowly adding the packages

Comment: although the production version works fine, so thats how i figured it had to do with the vue HMR in dev mode

Comment: Any solution for this?